# What to do when the correct answer to my question is a comment to a wrong answer?

Tags: discussion

I made a question. I received an answer. This answer does not resolve my problem.

Another user commented this "wrong" answer, with the solution to my problem, i.e., providing the correct answer.

I upvoted the comment... but the question remains "unanswered", because I won't accept the wrong answer as correct... right?

What should I do, then? The answer I want to accept is a comment!

See it here: [Which INPUT rules do I need to add to iptables so apt (apt-get, aptitude) can work (update, upgrade, search, install)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67441/which-input-rules-do-i-need-to-add-to-iptables-so-apt-apt-get-aptitude-can-wo)

Denwerko answer didn't work for me. The solution which worked for me is right below, in Riccardo Murri's comment.

Comment: I updated his answer. You might now want to accept the answer. Remember this is not just a Q&A site, but a kind of wiki. We want good questions ans answers to show up. Fixing other's answers are accepted culture here. Even many of my answers have been tweaked with

Comment: @Manish: what I have to say is too big for a comment, I am adding as an answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to ask the user to put their comment in an answer. In most cases they will gladly do this because they will earn at least 15 reputation. If they don't, feel free to post the comment as an answer yourself (perhaps making a note of the user that posted the comment). You will be able to accept your own answer within 2 days.

Comment: +1 for writing quicker.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious thing is to add another comment begging the commenter to post his comment as answer.

Comment: Is there a way to send a message directly to the user?

Comment: As far as i know the OP (original poster) always gets a note in his inbox. Prefixing a user name with a @-sign in a comment will behave the same way. There is no way to send nonpublic messages to other users.

Comment: I left a @ reply to `riccardo-murri`, so hopefully he will get a notification on top-left area next time when he logs to any stackexchange network site.

Answer (score 0):

@Manish: Interesting. By doing this, IMO, you frustrated everyone involved at the same time.

Myself - because you gave big credit to me as provider of the answer. I provided the question, and Riccardo provided the answer. He deserves the credit (and reputation points). Not me.

Denwerko - his suggestion has been erased. What appears now as his answer does not contain a single word of what he has written.

Lekensteyn - he already had included the working solution in his answer. I should have accepted his answer... I only wanted to know if credit + reputation could go to Riccardo, which answered quickly and correctly, although in a comment. Now, credit coming to me + points going to Denwenko is unfair to Lekensteyn.

Riccardo - he only provided a good answer, and now is involved in this "mess". :-)

George Edison and bernd_k - they provided nice suggestions, as ANSWERS, but they are witnessing another super-powered COMMENT steal the scene, again.

Yourself - you tried to do a good thing, but instead of providing a good answer... you are probably also frustrated now because of this reaction from me.

More questions:

1) Can you undo your edit?
2) How can I contact Riccardo, following George + Bernd suggestion, asking him to post his comment as an answer?

Maybe Denwenko himself could fix his own answer. Maybe I could simply accept Lekensteyn answer. Maybe it's just me, creating a storm in a glass of water. Sorry. I really disliked to see myself credited there.

Comment: Answering your `First point` - If the credits are misplaced. They can be fixed. Not a big issue. Going to `Second issue` - This is an issue. I once kept on updating my own answer in a timeline fashion. It is more of wiki and not a forum. `Third issue` - If his answer is proper then choose which one you want to accept as correct answer.

Comment: I have rolledback the changes. All questions and answers are versioned like a wiki. You can rollback or move to any revision you want. About contacting `Ricardo`, he has not left any contact on his profile. So I am afraid it is tough. You can just leave a comment. Same with `Denwerko`. Only `Lekensteyn` has his Launchpad profile information present. BTW if you did not like you to be credited or see any such mistake, just change it. In case you don't have permissions, it will go in moderation queue which any moderator can approve

Comment: I don't know what criteria you choose for selecting correct answers, but use your wisdom to choose. I would go for the answer which not only answers my question but also provides an extended answer since this is not just for my solution, but people who might have the same problem can have a look. When they find a good answered marked as Accepted, then helps everyone

Comment: @Manish Sinha: Thanks for your patience. Please, accept my apologies for creating this situation. Also, thanks for your effort and all the actions taken (rollback, comments, contact). Really kind. Truly special. I think all we have learned something new from this experience.

Comment: @j-bruni: Actually I was not offended or anything. I can understand that someone who is not habituated to AskUbuntu can feel update/rollback unusual. Happy to help